# Function on php redirect

Tags: php

Is there anyway to trigger a certain function if the page was redirected to by a certain page?
I wanted to trigger a paragraph after being redirected from my registration page to index page
example: when i signup and get redirected, i want a text to popup or appear thanking me for registering

thank you in advance

Comment: You can redirect to /yourpage?thankyou=1

Comment: Open popup on onload event of redirected page.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a SESSION on your registration page and on your index page check if a certain SESSION['var'] isset and if so then display your welcome/thanks message

check up on [Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

Comment: "You can start a SESSION on your registration page and on your index page check if a certain SESSION['var'] isset and if so then display your welcome/thanks message"

How to do so?

Comment: Read the link that I so graciously provided for you

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You just pass whatever parameters you want in the form:

`<form action="submit.php?code=thanks" method="get">`

then, on the submitted handler page you look for those parameters like so:

```
if ($_GET['code'] == thanks) {
   echo "Thanks for joining us!";
}
```

Comment: I still cant do it as i am new to php .I used the following code to redirect:-

if($insert_user) {
header('Location:  http://surfine.comeze.com/?thanks');
}

Comment: I just checked out your page so now I know how to help you.

Comment: You really should redirect to another page where you can have a welcome message waiting.  If you redirect to the same page as where people are signing up it's gonna make this 10 x harder to program, you being a beginner and all.

Comment: I guess so, but I'd like to learn the session ones and am already working on it. If I use the session method, do i have to start a session in registration.php and obtain it in index.php and set to echo my message?

Comment: @user2125922: The problem is you basically have to hide the entire page with a PHP conditional if, else if, else statement and only show what is relevant based on if the `$_SESSION` is started or not.